# Redirecting all Requests on a Domain to a Specific URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

It's been a long time since I've used Apache (a *very* long time) and even then I didn't really do much URL rewriting or anything like that, just simple hosting.  But now I'm trying to piece together a simple redirect for a small business that's re-branded to a new domain.

The way it's set up is that the host for the old domain has a web control panel based redirect to a specific URL, which is a "looking for the old us?" page on the new domain.  All requests are redirected, but they carry with them the entire request path which results in a 404 on the new site.

I've been looking through some Apache documentation and some examples I can find online, but I'm not quite there yet.  Where I've left off so far is with something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*looking-for-blah.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/looking-for-blah [L,R=301]
```

The idea is that any request coming in for any path which contains `looking-for-blah`, regardless of what's before or after it, should go to the explicit `http://newsite.com/looking-for-blah`.  So when the old host redirects somebody to:

```
http://newsite.com/looking-for-blah/foo/baz
```

They get redirected by the new site to:

```
http://newsite.com/looking-for-blah
```

However, it doesn't seem to be catching the incoming requests and redirecting them.  Am I missing some fundamental concept in the `RewriteCond`?  Maybe there's a better way to do this that I haven't even considered?

**Edit:** Here's the current state of the .htaccess as a whole:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN custom redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule looking-for-icamp http://empow.me/looking-for-icamp [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END icamp redirect
```

But doing a simple `wget` on `http://empow.me/looking-for-icamp/foo` results in a 404 instead of the desired 301.

Comment: The `RewriteCond` isn't even necessary. You could just do `RewriteRule looking-for-blah http://newsite.com/looking-for-blan [L,R=301]` (Apache doesn't need the `.*` as it will match as a substring if not `^$` anchored) but what you have ought to work anyway. Are you missing the `RewriteEngine On` to initialize it?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: That definitely looks simpler, but it's not doing the trick in this case either.  I can't help but wonder if something else is getting in the way as well.  I've updated the question with more information about the `.htaccess` along with the actual URL for verification.

Comment: oh, Wordpress is involved.  Move your rule _before_ the wordpress rules. Otherwise, it probably matches `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` and gets sent into WP routing. (and you only need one `<IfModule></IfModule>` around everything, also only one `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase`)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I'd love nothing more than to de-involve WordPress :)  The other `IfModule`s were auto-generated, so I figured I'd maintain the pattern in case the framework needed something.  In any event, moving to the top definitely worked, but uncovered a logical error I hadn't thought of... The redirect is circular :)  When a request comes in for the target URL, it still trips it.  So I need to change the match pattern to require _something_ after the URL.  Appending a `.+` fixed that, though.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wordpress default catch-all routing is matching your rule before it can be reached, so your rule will need to be placed *above* any Wordpress rewrites.  I also added a `RewriteCond` to be more explicit about the circular rewrite avoidance than your `.+` trick, which seems a little hacky to me and would be hard to understand on later readings.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN custom redirect

# This must take place before the Wordpress redirect to index.php
# Added condition to avoid circular rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/looking-for-icamp$ 
RewriteRule looking-for-icamp http://empow.me/looking-for-icamp [L,R=301]
# END icamp redirect

# Note - you had two identical WP blocks. I've removed one.

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# This rule was the one blocking your custom rule earlier....
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```